# Is Azure service bus a message broker and also an event store?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azureservicebus

I am reading on microservice architecture, event driven architecture and event sourcing. Is Azure service bus a message broker and also an event store? Is it the only way to implement event sourcing?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to event sourcing, **[Eventhub](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/event-hubs/)** can be used to store the events. It uses Blob storage or Data lake as the event store. Whereas service bus also can be considered but there are some limitations

Comment: Is it the only way to implement event sourcing?

Comment: Well, you have different options, but this is the most recommended way. You can also have a look at changefeed with cosmosdb

Answer (score 0):

Event Store in context of Event sourcing is the formal store where you would store all the domain events that happened to domain. Azure Service Bus is  simply message broker to keep the events/messages until they are processed.

When an event arrives in service bus you would need to process that and save that event in Event store. Event store can be SQL/NoSQL depends on your case so It can be SQL DB, or CosmosDB. For Event sourcing you need to save all the domain events as they happen with their version number. Events are immutable and you would then replay the events to reach the current state of the system.

You can read more about event sourcing here [Event Sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/event-sourcing)